# Swift: Typecasting Objects That Have Identical Selectors

Tags: objective-c, swift, casting, selector

## The Situation

Suppose I have two classes:

```
class Foo: NSObject {
    var specialProperty: String = "hello"
}

class Bar: NSObject {
    var specialProperty: String = "goodbye"
}
```

Now suppose I'm working with a collection that I **KNOW** contains only `Foo` and `Bar` instances. I know that **every** object in the array will respond to the `specialProperty` selector, so in Objective-C I could just cast, like this:

```
for id thing in arrayOfThings
{
    NSLog(@"specialProperty: %@", ((Foo *)thing).specialProperty);
}
```

How can I approach this in Swift? I cannot add a common superclass to `Foo` and `Bar`, nor can I add a protocol to them. In reality, `Foo` and `Bar` are `NSManagedObject` subclasses that represent model items in my app.

---

## Selector?

I have considered this approach:

```
let collection: [AnyObject] // Assume this contains Foo and Bar instances.
let sel: Selector = #selector(setter: Foo.specialProperty)

for item in collection 
{
    if item.respondsToSelector(sel) 
    {
        instance.perform(sel, with: "new value")
    } 
}
```

Will calling `sel` on instances of `Bar` work, even though I told Swift the type for the selector was `Foo.`? It seems like it should because the Objective-C selector mechanism doesn't care what the class of the Object is; that's not part of the selector signature. But I'm unsure if there's something in the Swift-ObjectiveC interaction that I'm overlooking.

---

## Context

I am migrating this app from Objective-C.

Comment: The Selector approach does work fine in a Playground. I'd just like confirmation that there isn't something more complex happening in the Swift-ObjC interaction, since Swift wants a concrete type for the selector (Foo.) and Objective-C doesn't care.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct approach to this, in both Objective C and Swift, is to use a protocol:

```
protocol Special {
    var specialProperty { get set }
}

class Foo: NSObject, Special {
    var specialProperty: String = "hello"
}

class Bar: NSObject, Special {
    var specialProperty: String = "goodbye"
}

let collection: [Special] = ...

for item in collection {
    item.specialProperty = "new value" 
}
```

Comment: yep, thanks. I don't have the ability to add a protocol in this case, which is what I put in the original post. That's why I'm looking to typecast. Rearchitecting the app from the ground up isn't doable---it's hundreds of thousands of lines of code. Foo and Bar in this case are auto-generated from Core Data and a complicated process; they aren't written by hand.

Comment: `var specialProperty { get set }` ?? Btw `item` is immutable

Comment: Hmm. Given that "Foo.h/m" and "Bar.h/m" are created by Core Data and the actual source doesn't exist (auto-generated by Xcode during build), I thought I wouldn't be able to declare that the classes adopt a protocol. What I CAN do is add a separate Swift file that declares the "Special" protocol and then uses an extension to declare that Foo and Bar adopt Special. Less than ideal, because I have to update my protocol whenever I add/remove/change properties for Foo and Bar in Core Data, but it does work.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can consider this approach as well

```
let collection: [AnyObject] // Assume this contains Foo and Bar instances.

for item in collection 
{
    guard let aFoo = item as? Foo else {
    guard let aBar = item as? Bar else { continue } 

    aBar.specialProperty = "New value"

    continue
    } 

    aFoo.specialProperty = "New value"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides using protocol, I believe it can also be done using optional cast

```
for item in collection 
{
    if let foo = item  as? Foo
    {
        // only when casting to Foo successfully
        foo.specialProperty
    } 
    if let bar = item  as? Bar
    {
        // only when casting to Bar successfully
        bar.specialProperty
    } 
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I suggested in my answer but using 'guard'.

Comment: This does not work. Foo is not convertible to Bar and Bar is not convertible to Foo.

Comment: There must be a misunderstanding. I'm not converting between Foo and Bar, I'm converting an item to Foo or Bar. The code above I have tested, it definitely works out.@Bryan